# i want to use if statement for multiple variables inside sql command

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, variables, if-statement

i am new to programming. Learning C# and using
visual studio

i made a file with two text boxes. the content of these text boxes
are transferred to another file using javascript

listfile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RunAjax1(custId) {
            var custId = document.getElementById("customerId").value;
            //var custName = document.getElementById("customerName").value;
            jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    url: "CustActions.aspx?id=" + custId +"&custName="+customerName,
                    type: "GET"
                }

                ).done(function (responseText) {
                    jQuery("#display").html(responseText)
                });
        }
        </script>
```

i want to use an if statement before an sql command in order to use one
or the two variables (whichever is not null). 
The customerid is integer, while the customerName is a string.

The code is as follows:

actionfile

```
<%      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
             string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM Customers where id= @_id";
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(Request["id"].ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.Add("custName_",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=Convert.ToChar(Request["custName"].ToString());
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             con.Open();
             dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
             con.Close();
         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write(string.Format(@"<tr>
                                                    <td>{0}</td>
                                                    <td>{1}</td>
```

That is i want a statement like the one that follows

```
if (_id is Notnull)
{
string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM Customers where id= @_id";

}
else
{

string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM Customers where customerName= @custName_";
```

}

plus variable declaration to the actionfile

Thanks

Comment: To do what I think it is that you want, you would have to declare _id as a nullable int, int?. Then you can see if _id is null by ` if (_id != null)` otherwise in C#, int variable are not null. But this is just a guess. Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%       SqlConnection con = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString());
         string cmdText = _id != null
                            ? @"SELECT * FROM Customers where id= @_id"
                            : @"SELECT * FROM Customers where customerName= @custName_";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(Request["id"].ToString());
         cmd.Parameters.Add("custName_",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=Convert.ToChar(Request["custName"].ToString());
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         con.Open();
         dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
         con.Close();
```

Is this what you want? However its not recommended to put so much code into your aspx files.

Comment: Aron, how will i declare the variables _id and custName_ before the sql query?
Because in your code 

 

    string cmdText = _id != null
                                ? @"SELECT * FROM Customers where id= @_id"
                                : @"SELECT * FROM Customers where customerName= @custName_";

visual studio is placing a red line under _id saying "that the name _id does not exist in the current context".
Except from the declaration of the  two variables _id and custName_
how will i get the values for them through the javascript that i am using ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its better to put make your code accept 2 parameters and then have the stored procedure handle the nulls and it have the if statement

like this

```
Create proc dosomething
(
-- initialized the values to null if no value is passed in 
@id tinyint = NULL
@CustomerName varchar 100 = NULL
)
BEGIN
if @tinyint is NULL and CustomerName is not null
 SELECT * FROM Customers where id= @id ";

END
BEGIN
if @CustomerName is NULL and @tinyint is NOT NULL
 SELECT * FROM Customers where customerName= @Customername";

END

BEGIN
if @CustomerName is NULL NOT  and @tinyint is NOT NULL
 SELECT * FROM Customers where (customerName= @Customername and id = @id) ";

END
```